# Couldn't find PerQuiz with 'id'=edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have encountered this error on several projects and can't seem to find my way out.  I'm trying to access my `per_quiz#edit` view, but it's looking for the `show` for a `per_quiz` with the `id` of "edit".

My routes are just `resources :per_quizzes` and my `per_quizzes_controller` is like this:

```
class PerQuizzesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in

    def show
      @per_quiz = PerQuiz.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @per_quiz = current_user.build_per_quiz
    end

    def create
      @per_quiz = PerQuiz.new

      @per_quiz.iper_code = params[:per_quiz][:iper_code]
      @per_quiz.myper_code = params[:per_quiz][:myper_code]


      @per_quiz.user = current_user

      if @per_quiz.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your personality saved successfully."
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your results failed to save."
        redirect_to welcome_index_path
      end
    end

    def edit
      @per_quiz = PerQuiz.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @per_quiz = PerQuiz.find(params[:id])

      @per_quiz.assign_attributes(per_quiz_params)

      if @per_quiz.save
        flash[:notice] = "Results were updated successfully."
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving your results. Please try again."
        redirect_to welcome_index_path
      end
    end

    private
    def per_quiz_params
      params.require(:per_quiz).permit(:iper_code, :myper_code)
    end
end
```

I didn't come in through a link, but rather typed in the `url` manually, so I don't think it's a linking issue.  Can anyone clarify why this error occurs?  I've looked at many SO posts and can't get a handle on it.

Comment: How are you trying to access? Can you show the path you're using?

Comment: @Kumar I typed in `http://localhost:3000/per_quizzes/edit`, which is the problem because the route is `/per_quizzes/:id/edit(.:format)`.  Thank you, I'm an idiot.  If you want to write it up as an answer I'll happily select it.

Comment: Haha.. well, it happens to us all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to mention that, you have to pass the resource id to your edit or update according to rails convention.

```
per_quizzes/:id/edit
```

Or if your using your rails helper to create the edit link, pass the resource or the resource id, it will create the edit link for you.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_per_quiz_path(@per_quiz) %>
```

Comment: I might actually not be the biggest idiot on the planet, because I'm getting an error elsewhere on the site for `edit_per_quiz_path(@per_quiz)` saying `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"per_quizzes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`...Any ideas?

Comment: :D . So do a `rake routes` in your terminal and find the `prefix` for your quiz edit route. I assumed its `per_quiz_edit_path` but it could be something else in your project. Let me know.

Comment: Yeah, it is `edit_per_quiz GET    /per_quizzes/:id/edit(.:format)     per_quizzes#edit`, which is why that error doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, its supposed to be `edit_per_quiz_path(@per_quiz). I'll change in my answer. Can you confirm if its working now?

Comment: Also do check if you're passing the right resource to your path, i.e., `@per_quiz`. Make sure it not nil.

Comment: Well it definitely is `nil` because I haven't created one yet, but it's in the `else` side of an `if` statement that says `<% if current_user.nil? || current_user.per_quiz.nil? %>`... so it shouldn't even appear...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122939/discussion-between-kumar-and-liz).

Comment: sorry I missed your invitation to chat yesterday.  I do appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: I rephrased the problem here, if you're curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416401/model-is-nil-but-if-else-statement-treating-it-like-it-exists