# Model is `Nil`, but if/else statement treating it like it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following `if` statement in my controller to direct a user to the `per_quiz#new` page if the user has not completed a `per_quiz` but to the `per_quiz#edit` page if they have taken one:

```
def new
  @per_quiz = current_user.build_per_quiz
  if current_user.per_quiz != nil
    redirect_to edit_per_quiz_path(current_user.per_quiz)
  end
end
```

I am on `localhost` as a user that has not taken a `per_quiz`, as I can tell by my `console`:

```
[2] pry(main)> User.first.per_quiz
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  PerQuiz Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "per_quizzes".* FROM "per_quizzes" WHERE "per_quizzes"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
=> nil
```

However, when I try to access the page I get an error that (I think) looks like I'm being directed to the wrong fork of the `if` statement:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"per_quizzes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

This is called on the `redirect_to` line of the controller.

Can anyone see what's going on here that's making it glitch?

Comment: Try `unless current_user.per_quiz.nil?`

Comment: @GokulM, no, that just gives me the same error.  I've tried a bunch of different phrasings...

Comment: Try to see what `puts current_user.per_quiz` prints.

Comment: It says `nil`.  That's what's strange.

Comment: It's really strange :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consulted the powers that be and ended up having to change it to this:

```
def new
 if current_user.per_quiz
   redirect_to edit_per_quiz_path(current_user.per_quiz)
   flash[:notice] = 'You already took this quiz'
 else
   @per_quiz = current_user.build_per_quiz
 end
end
```

Apparently having the build before the `if` statement was plunging the quiz into a nil-but-simultaneously-not-nil, Schrodinger's cat type of situation.